# GCM response is invalid registration id for Android apps

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on a webservice for android appliction's chat system, where I am using GCM(google cloud messaging). But always I am getting invalid registration response by GCM. I know this can cause by formatting of the registration ID that I pass to the server, but I am sure it matches the registration ID the phone receives in the chat system.

Here is my code(where I amsending reciever phone number gcm registarion id):

```
if (isset($_POST["regId"]) && isset($_POST["message"]) && isset($_POST['acceptor_no'])) {
    include_once './config.php';
    //include_once './db_connect.php';
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    // selecting database
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    $regId = $_POST["regId"];
    $accepterPhone=$_POST['acceptor_no'];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $arr=array();
    $selectDeviceId=mysql_query("select gcm_regid from gcm_users where phone='".$accepterPhone."'");
    $selectDeviceIdRow=mysql_fetch_array($selectDeviceId);
    $accepterDeviceId=$selectDeviceIdRow['gcm_regid'];
    include_once './GCM.php';

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array($accepterDeviceId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
    //$arr['response'] = array('msg'=>$message,'status'=>true,'phone'=>$accepterPhone,'deviceId'=>$regId,'accepterDeviceId'=>$accepterDeviceId);
    //echo json_encode($arr);
  if(isset($result))
  {
    $abc=json_encode($result);
    echo $abc;
    }else
    {
    //echo json_encode($result);
    $msg="Does not Exists";
    $arr['response'] = array('msg'=>$msg,'status'=>false);
            $abc=json_encode($arr);
            echo json_encode($arr);
    }
    }else
    {
    $msg="No data Available";
    $arr['response'] = array('msg' => $msg ,'status'=>false);
    $abc=json_encode($arr);
    echo json_encode($arr);
    }
```

But I am always getting "Does not Exist" response if I print json response in this condition then it says "invalid registration".

Please suggest me how to solve this type of error in GCM response.

Thanks

Comment: do u know sender id and registration id in gcm android

Comment: `$registatoin_ids` is having reciever registration id.....

Comment: Check This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921189/how-to-parse-gcm-respond-to-remove-invalid-registration-id-from-server-with-php

Comment: already checked and tried... :(

Comment: Have u registered your app on Google Consol

Comment: yes Naveen..........

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60379/discussion-between-dinesh-and-naveen-tamrakar).

Comment: whatever u update first uninstall app from device and than Reagain Run app and check logcat and show error

Comment: check the send notification format

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you copied the apid from UrbanAirship? If so, look at my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27071675/679049