# InvalidRegistration both on C2DM & GCM

Tags: php, android, push, google-cloud-messaging, android-c2dm

I'm trying to send Push Notifications via C2DM / GCM to an Android Application via PHP.
No matter which i use, i keep getting the following :

For GCM : 
{"multicast_id":7672049265453358197,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

For C2DM : Error=InvalidRegistration

After reading allot about this issue all day I'm still clueless as to why this is an InvalidRegistration as if i take the registatoin_id and use it to send a test push message via Urban Airship it works.

- Notice that this is not an auth issue as i get a [http_code] => 200 back from google and not 401.
- If i send an empty registatoin_id or even omit just one char from it the error message changes to "MissingRegistration".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you copied the `apid` from UrbanAirship then that's the problem:

http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/glossary.html#term-apid

> Airship Push Identifier
>
> APID
>
> APIDs identify devices with transient registration IDs, such as Windows devices.
>   These identifiers are version 4 UUIDs, and are 36 characters long, including dashes.

You need to get the device information from http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua.html#get--api-apids-(APID) in the `"gcm_registration_id"` property. That's the registration id needed.

It seems you need to then keep track of that registration id as it is transient as suggested by UrbanAirship. But that's another topic.