# PHP: GCM Invalid Registration when passing array to function

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am encountering a very strange issue with my php code I have set up for google cloud messaging.

Current I have the following function to send a push notification:

```
function sendPushNotification($user_token_list, $message)
{
    global $gcm_api_key, $errors;
    $data = array('message' => $message);
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $post_data = array (
        "registration_ids" => $user_token_list,
        "data"             => array("message" => $message)
        );
    $header = array (
        'Authorization: key='.$gcm_api_key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post_data));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) $errors[] = array('PUSH_NOTIFICATION_FAILURE' => curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

`$message`is the message to be included in the downstream and `$user_token_list` is of type array whose elements contain VALID registration ids.

The function I use to construct the `$user_token_list` array is the following:

```
function getDeviceTokensFromUserList($recipients, $website)
{
    $token_list = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($recipients); ++$i)
    {
        $token_list[] = getDeviceTokenFromUserid($recipients[$i], $website);
    }
    return $token_list;
}
```

However, upon sending a downstream request, I am given the error:

> InvalidRegistration

However when I do a `var_dump` on `$user_token_list`it gives me a registration id

> duICFkjL5I4:APA91bF_asp9iDmNvMWUX58nPU8bj8kWua8ISiAoUw0KvYai5n37yp-qRlQrl2jPhTPY-a8KMq-XXXXXXXXX

and if I hard code the registration id into the `sendPushNotification` function, it doesn't give me an error
i.e

```
$post_data = array (
        "registration_ids" => array("duICFkjL5I4:APA91bF_asp9iDmNvMWUX58nPU8bj8kWua8ISiAoUw0KvYai5n37yp-qRlQrl2jPhTPY-a8KMq-XXXXXXXXX"),
        "data"             => array("message" => $message)
        );
```

meaning the registration id is valid and registered with gcm.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Can you make sure the length of the key is the same as the one you need? Make sure no white space etc...

Comment: Just to be sure, if `$user_token_list` is truly an array, `var_dump` will output its array structure, not just the string value you showed.

Comment: Yes, var_dump outputs the array structure... The string is the exact same length..

Answer (score 0):

According with Android GCM's architectural overview you have an invalidRegistration error when:

Invalid Registration ID Check the formatting of the registration ID that you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration ID the phone receives in the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent and that you're not truncating it or adding additional characters. Happens when error code is InvalidRegistration.

Have check the part for receive downstream message: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Here's a related Stack overflow ticket: [How to parse GCM respond to remove invalid registration id from server with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921189/how-to-parse-gcm-respond-to-remove-invalid-registration-id-from-server-with-php)